# jQuery Sliders Moving at the same time - out of sync by one step

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

I have the following code:-

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('.slider').each(function() {
    var $el = jQuery(this);
    $el.slider({
        range: "max",
        min: $el.data('min'),
        max: $el.data('max'),
        value: $el.data('value'),
        step: $el.data('step'),
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            var percent = (100 / (jQuery(this).data('max') - jQuery(this).data('min'))) * jQuery(this).slider('value');

            jQuery('.slider').not(this).each(function() {
                jQuery(this).slider(
                    'value', 
                    ((jQuery(this).data('max') - jQuery(this).data('min')) / 100) * percent
                );
            });
            jQuery('.slider').each(function() {
                var thisTarget = jQuery(this).data('target');
                var thisValue = jQuery(this).slider('option','value');

                console.log(thisTarget,thisValue);

                jQuery(thisTarget+' span').html(thisValue);
            });

        },
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider" data-min="3800" data-max="30000" data-value="3848" data-step="500" data-target=".calc-deposit"></div>
<div class="slider" data-min="15400" data-max="120000" data-value="15393" data-step="2000" data-target=".calc-loan"></div>
<div class="slider" data-min="57000" data-max="450000" data-value="57724" data-step="7500" data-target=".calc-mortgage"></div>

<div class="calc-deposit calc-center">£<span></span></div>
<div class="calc-loan calc-center">£<span></span></div>
<div class="calc-mortgage calc-center">£<span></span></div>
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/08u3w3hg/)

It's all working as expected but as you drag the sliders, the other sliders seem to be either a step ahead or a step behind depending which way you are dragging the slider.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: assign some ID to that slider DIV and using that ID create slider...

Comment: Using repeated class it always behave like now...

Comment: You should just delaying the slide event callback called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delay the callback of slide event, e.g:

```
jQuery('.slider').each(function() {
  var $el = jQuery(this);
  $el.slider({
    range: "max",
    min: $el.data('min'),
    max: $el.data('max'),
    value: $el.data('value'),
    step: $el.data('step'),
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
      this.timeout = setTimeout(updateSliders.bind(this, event, ui))
    }
  });
});

function updateSliders(event, ui) {
  var percent = (100 / (jQuery(this).data('max') - jQuery(this).data('min'))) * jQuery(this).slider('value');

  jQuery('.slider').not(this).each(function() {
    jQuery(this).slider(
      'value',
      ((jQuery(this).data('max') - jQuery(this).data('min')) / 100) * percent
    );
  });
  jQuery('.slider').each(function() {
    var thisTarget = jQuery(this).data('target');
    var thisValue = jQuery(this).slider('option', 'value');

    console.log(thisTarget, thisValue);

    jQuery(thisTarget + ' span').html(thisValue);
  });
}
```

### Updated jsFiddle